# Ticketing from SkyTeam and operating by Oneworld: Should the miles go to my SkyTeam-affiliated or my Oneworld-affiliated frequent flyer program?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs, oneworld, skyteam

A while ago, I took a flight. I'd like to add the miles from this flight to my one of my frequent flyer programs. I have a frequent flyer program with each of the 3 major [airline alliances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_alliance), namely Oneworld, Star Alliance, and SkyTeam.

Flight info for the first leg of the flight:

- The ticketing airline is a member of the [SkyTeam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SkyTeam) alliance.
- The operating airline is a member of the [Oneworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oneworld) alliance.

For the other legs, the ticketing airline was the same as the operating airline (it is the same as the ticketing airline for the first leg, which is member of the SkyTeam alliance). All the legs of the flight were on a single ticket.

For the first leg, should I submit a request add the miles to my SkyTeam-affiliated frequent flyer program or my Oneworld-affiliated frequent flyer program?

Comment: Is the flight a codeshare? If so, is the flight number in the ticket from the ticketing or operating airline?

Comment: @jcaron thanks, on the ticket, the flight number of the first leg is expressed as the flight number from the operating airline.